# Direction field of complicated equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following differential equation I would like to graph differential equation:
`dy/dx = \frac{2x}{x^4+1}`. I would also like to graph the solution that goes through the point `(1,1)`. Here's what I currently have:

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalenable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=2*\x/(\x^4+1);}]
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    domain=-4:4,
    ]

    \def\xmax{4} \def\xmin{-4}
    \def\ymax{4} \def\ymin{-4}
    \def\nx{15}
    \def\ny{15}
    \def\yo{1}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx})}
      \addplot [blue,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}]
        (0,0)--($(0,0)!2mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
    }

    \addplot [<->,red] {-1/4*pi+rad(atan(x^2))+1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.30     }
          
?
```

I originally had `\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}` in replace of  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx})}` because I don't need to pass in the \y since the function doesn't use it. But even when I do so and update the function definition from `f(\x) = ...` to `f(\x,\y) = ...`, the program still crashes giving:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.32   \end{axis}
                 
?
```

I'm aware of the following questions. I've used them and none of them worked out:

1. [How to draw slope fields with all the possible solution curves in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139064/how-to-draw-slope-fields-with-all-the-possible-solution-curves-in-latex)
2. [How to plot a function and its derivative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437675/how-to-plot-a-function-and-its-derivative)
3. [Differential Equation direction plot with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139114/differential-equation-direction-plot-with-pgfplots/)

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment ? No time now, but probably there is a problem there...

Comment: I don't think that that's my problem though.

Comment: Hi.  First, I think that your equation can be solved explicitly (using a change of variable $t=x^2$).  Then you can draw the solution.  Second, I gave some answers that can be applied to such problems; see [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663824/graphing-system-of-ode-flows/665528#665528) and [(2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685528/stream-plot-in-tikz-with-singularities/687227#687227).

Comment: `\foreach` does not work as you expect in `\axis` use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.  `shift` is not a suitable option to `\addplot`.  You need to specify plot type. You can not just use `--` inside a plot. Maybe you want a `quiver` plot? It is difficult to tell, what you are trying to do. Can you draw a picture of the desired output?

Comment: Please add some more information on your desired output